# nodejs pushing to array inside for loop with requests

Tags: javascript, node.js

Starting out with Node without any async knowledge and am wondering how I can push data as part of a callback into an array. The output array is declared but is undefined when its referenced within the request callback. Is there a simple way to just pass that variable into the callback function scope?

Ideally, I'd like to send back an array of the results from each request made back to the caller.

```
const request = require('request');

module.exports = {

apiRatingCall: function (input, callback) {

var output = []

  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  var options = {
    url: 'someAPIURL' + '?longitude=' + input[i].longitude + '&latitude=' + input[i].latitude + '&name=' + input[i].name,
    headers: {
      'x-api-version': 2
    }
  };

  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

      var info = JSON.parse(body)
      output.push(info) // this is not working as ouput is undefined at this point
    }
  })
  }
  callback(output)
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my answer maybe not very normative in programming by it is only way for this problem I promise

```
module.exports = {

apiRatingCall: function (input, callback) {

var output = []

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
var options = {
  url: 'someAPIURL' + '?longitude=' + input[i].longitude + '&latitude=' +    input[i].latitude + '&name=' + input[i].name,
 headers: {
  'x-api-version': 2
 }
};

 request(options, function (error, response, body) {
   if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

    var info = JSON.parse(body)
    output.push(info) // this is not working as ouput is undefined at this    point
   }
 })
 }
 setTimeout(function(){
   callback(output)
 },500)

 }
}
```

Comment: If the network connection is not fast enough and all the response do not come back by 500 mils then what would you do?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the end of `for` loop and execute your `callback`

```
var loopCallback = function(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
     var info = JSON.parse(body)
     output.push(info)
  }
  if( i == input.length - 1){ //checking index for completion of loop
    callback(output);
  }
}

request(options, loopCallback})
```

Comment: Ajax requests don't usually get their responses in the same order they were issued. Putting the callback on the last one is not going to guarantee that the others have finished.

Comment: Great - but the output variable is still null and didn't get data pushed to it. Is there a way to push to the array within the requests callback?

Comment: @4castleThank you, You are right, we can consider this as workaround until we have a proper solution.

Comment: @alex99_14, if this `output` accessible inside `for` loop, reassign this to some other variable and use that inside `request` call back

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja Sorry , this makes no sense.

Comment: Try the updated code with a local `callback` to access local `variables`.

Comment: [i] is always equal to the max length of the array that the for loop is going through so im guessing it's just that im doing something wrong and should be using the async module. running your suggested code does not work and the callback is never called since [i] is always the max length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the async module. It is a good module to do async operation with array and collection if you do not want to use bluebird and promises.

Do npm install async -S.

```
const request = require('request');
const async = require('async);

module.exports = {

  apiRatingCall: function (inputs, callback) {

  var output = []


  async.each(inputs, function(input, cb) {
      var options = {
      url: 'someAPIURL' + '?longitude=' + input.longitude + '&latitude=' + input.latitude + '&name=' + input.name,
      headers: {
       'x-api-version': 2
      }
      request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

          var info = JSON.parse(body)
          output.push(info); 
          cb();
        }else{
          //if any of the request fails then return error
          cb(error);
        }
    })

    }, function(err){
      if(!err){
         return callback(output);
      }else{
        //if any of the request return error
        return callback(err);
      }
   });
}
```